# Magento 2 Admin login Problem

Tags: magento-2.1

I am able to login to the admin control panel the first time and when I logout and login again it get this message:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: `` INSERT INTO `admin_user_session` (`session_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `ip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ``

But this works again when I get the empty `ADMIN_USER_SESSION` table in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A DB BACKUP**

You can verify that your admin_user_session table has the primary key set to auto-increment with this query:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA 'magento_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'admin_user_session';
```

If you see that auto-increment is turned off, then you can fix it with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE 'admin_user_session' MODIFY COLUMN 'session_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

However, if you need to do that, that is a good indication that either your DB import failed or you have some custom functionality with admin sessions that is blocking the auto-increment functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**CODE USED:**

SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA 'magento_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'admin_user_session' LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

**ERROR CODE:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''magento_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'admin_user_session' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

---

And when i tried to ALTER:

---

**CODE USED:**
**ALTER TABLE 'admin_user_session' MODIFY COLUMN 'session_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;**

**ERROR CODE:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''admin_user_session' MODIFY COLUMN 'session_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below query your issue get resolved.

```
ALTER TABLE `admin_user_session` MODIFY COLUMN 'session_id' INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```